# How to use helper method with input_html with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to change the id of a simple_form input select element using a helper method, i.e.

```
<%= f.input :no_players, collection: (0..4), input_html: { id_for_trigger } %>
```

where the helper method is

```
def id_for_trigger
    return unless @select_trigger
    'id: :no_players_trigger'
end
```

but this gives following error message

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
input_html: { id_for_trigger }  );
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly braces signify that you need to pass in a hash. Try this...

```
input_html: { id: id_for_trigger }
```

`:input_html` sets a html attribute so you need to specify what attribute you are trying to set.

So, if this is the case, your helper should be....

```
def id_for_trigger
  return 'your_default_id' unless @select_trigger
  'no_players_trigger'
end
```

The `your_default_id` is the id that the select element normally has. In this way, any other pages that use css or javascript attached to `your_default_id` will not be affected.